# when i set background size background-repeat none doesnt work

Tags: css

When I do the following code, it works up until the point where i resize the page, the background image stars to repeat, even thought background-repeat is set to none. Any reason for this, you can view the page live [here](http://update.mrskitson.ca/)

```
#mainPage{
    background-image: url(../images/home.JPG);
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: none;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's `no-repeat`, not `none`:

```
#mainPage{
    background-image: url(../images/home.JPG);
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Whether or not you set `background-size` shouldn't make a difference.